# Usage of number in grammar

Tags: grammaticality

I have seen pepole saying 'station is next but one'.can we write that 'station is one next.i can remember i heard it but i am not sure.i have search the google but did not find any answer

Comment: The second sentence should be "The station is the next one" similar to "next but one" in the first sentence.

Comment: But if two station after present one can i say one next

Comment: No, we don't say that.

Comment: Ok thank you for your suggestion

Comment: We might say "my station is **the** one next" but more usually "my station is the next one."

Comment: Which station are you trying to refer to? The "next station" is the one coming up. The "next but one" is the one after that. Then comes the "next but two", the "next but three" and so on.